# Handrail Installation (Interior Stairs) using Kregg Jig & Screws

Tags: installation

Good afternoon.  I'm installing some new newel posts and a new handrail for our interior stairs.  For attaching the handrail to the newel post, it appears the typical installation calls for rail and post fastener.  However, instead of the rail and post fastener, I'm considering using Kregg Pocket Hole Jig with 3-inch screws.  I'm installing a square handrail and will be painting it.  I'm thinking 2 screws (top and bottom) of the handrail to attach to the newel post would be adequate.  I don't see any posts of anyone doing this so I'm a bit hesitant, but I don't know why it wouldn't work nicely.  Can you think of any concerns with this approach?

Comment: More information would definitely be in order to offer any responses regarding a railing design.  Please include some sketches (or photos) showing the material (species) and size of the rail, the size and spacing of the balusters and newel posts and how they are attached to each other and the stair assembly. If you are replacing existing posts, how are they attached to the stairs (Duplicating that attachment should be adequate)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I would simply not consider pocket-hole screws for this application (for clarity, with glue as well but assuming no other joinery). Test after test shows they're the weakest of almost all joinery options for various right-angle connections; not weak, just weakest. This is still perfectly acceptable for standard use-cases but this is very much not one of those, not by a long chalk. Unless much more information is provided that would assuage the innate worries I would strongly recommend a rethink.... with my standard caveat not to needlessly reinvent the wheel :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, codes in North America typically call for railings to withstand 200 pounds in any direction. Personally, I doubt that a couple of pocket screws are up to that. I'm very open to differing opinions, though.

Perhaps you could install a couple of sturdy dowels and rely on the pocket screws to pull the railing to the post, rather than (potentially) bear the force alone.

Comment: I've learned that pocket screws are not particularly a strong method of attachment, but your suggestion to use dowel pins would address that nicely, especially when combined with glue.